# Is there a word to describe a person who gets uspet at work when he feels others are not working as hard as him?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a guy working for me who is at risk within his job. This is because he has, on a couple of occasions walked off the job he had been given as he felt he was working hard and the Boss running the area wasn't.

When approached he often cites Team Leaders being lazy etc, the guy is actually a good worker, but by no means a superstar. The Team Leaders are good workers who, while not working as hard (not carrying out manual tasks), they are in fact doing the job they are employed to do, very well.

Is there a term for this type of reaction or person?

Comment: I doubt there is a specific term for this. The entire thing sounds very exploitative....

Answer (score 1):

***prima donna***

> disapproving:
> someone who demands to be treated in a special way and is difficult to please:

[_Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prima-donna)

I actually sympathize with your guy. I  have found myself in the same position once or twice.

Comment: Also, entitled. I'm right and everyone else is wrong.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Many times when Americans hear that, they think of a "Karen"...

Comment: @KannE https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/karen/

Comment: I don’t think *prima donna* captures the complaining aspect of this person. Closure was premature because of this omission. That said, I still can’t think of a word to fit the definition well so perhaps closure has made no difference anyway. The fellow is just a whinger.